# Android ViewBinding sometimes return null at binding object so I got null pointer exception when try to access a view

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Exact error log from Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.schonell.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding.errorMessageTV' on a null object reference
       at com.schonell.ui.activity.LoginActivity.showErrorMessage(LoginActivity.java:297)
       at com.schonell.ui.activity.LoginActivity.access$400(LoginActivity.java:59)
       at com.schonell.ui.activity.LoginActivity$2.onFailure(LoginActivity.java:286)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:80)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8587)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

My implementation are follows and layout name: activity_login.xml:

```
private ActivityLoginBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
}
```

When a error message returned from login button action I try to update the message at this view [errorMessageTV] and got the above error. Views updated at this method.

```
private void showErrorMessage(final String message) {
    binding.errorMessageTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.errorMessageTV.setText(message);
}
```

and called from here

```
public void activityLoginSubmit(View view) {

        hideErrorMessage();

        email = binding.emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        password = binding.passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            showErrorMessage(context.getString(R.string.please_fill_in_all_required_fields));
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            showErrorMessage(context.getString(R.string.please_fill_in_all_required_fields));
            return;
        }



        submitRemoteLogin();

    }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that someone downloaded an .APK of your app rather than getting the .AAB off the Play Store. When this happens, the app can crash immediately because the .APK doesn't contain the resources that are specific to the user's device (ie, resources specified with resource qualifiers).

Comment: The application has over one thousand active user and use the app regularly but this error happen/report only 5-6 time per week. I'm not sure about your answer that this is the cause.